# How could I add shadow and floating text on TextView (android)

Tags: android, textview, shadow, floating

How could I add shadow and floating text on TextView

I can have one of them at one TextView, but I can't prepare both of them at same time

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using `android:shadowColor="@color/black" android:shadowDx="1"
 android:shadowDy="1"` in the `TextView`?

Comment: Yes, it's doesn't work, I wandering why android didn't support this :(